# In Adobe Connect can I edit an existing meeting to use a different template?

Tags: adobe-connect

I have an instance of Adobe Connect 8 that we are running. I already have quite a few meetings in the system that are scheduled to be run at some point in the future.

Recently I have started to use a template for new meetings, but I want to know if it is possible to use this template against any existing meetings in the system?

If it is not possible what are the 'get around' options I have? Would I be forced to enter each of the existing meetings and try to replicate the template prior to any participants joining?